# Environment Variables - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, environment-variables, typeerror

I am attempting to create a web crawler utilizing Selenium via python. I have to login into a website and attempted to use two environment variables instead of hard coding my credentials into the script. However when I attempt to do so I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/KAR/Desktop/Web Scraping /Clicky2.py", line 28, in <module>
    username_box.send_keys(USERNAME)
  File "/Users/KAR/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/Users/KAR/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

As for my code: the code provided works when the credentials are hard coded but, I would prefer to have environment variables.

To be as specific as possible - the issue is that when I use environment variables to attempt to login using Selenium I receive an error as seen above.

If someone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
import requests
import os

#path to chromedriver
DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
#environment variables credentials for Clicky
#USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')
USERNAME = 'user'
#PASSWORD = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
PASSWORD = 'password'

#allows me to put Selenium in headless mode or without running GUI
options = Options()
options.headless = True

#opens Chrome, goes to Clicky login
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get('https://clicky.com/user/login')
print(driver.current_url)
print('Clicky is opened')
sleep(1)

username_box = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
username_box.clear()
username_box.send_keys(USERNAME)
sleep(1)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_box.clear()
password_box.send_keys(PASSWORD)
sleep(1)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_name("submit_button")
login_button.click()

print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables?

Comment: what happens if you try to print the environment variables? They may not be getting set properly.  Also, personally, if I'm using PyCharm or something like that, when I update environment variables they don't get caught by PyCharm unless I close & re-open it.

Comment: After printing them they both return 'None'. I have the credentials set up in a separate python file. I imported os and reference getenv and environ.get methods to call on them. I did a similar method when I was using request to web scrape and it worked. Not sure what the discrepancies are between how you would set them up for selenium instead of for request

Comment: I am also using Visual Studio Code

Comment: You still haven't said how you're setting the environment variables.

Comment: Well, then we know what the problem is - it's in how (or when, where, etc.) they're being set. Are you using Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: *- = new line* import os - os.environ['USERNAME'] = 'user' -os.environ['PASSWORD'] = 'password'

Comment: I am using mac.

Comment: Read this re: setting Mac environment variables, and use the commands mentioned to check and see if it's set correctly after doing that before running your script again. https://medium.com/@youngstone89/setting-up-environment-variables-in-mac-os-28e5941c771c

Comment: Where are you doing `os.environ['USERNAME'] = 'user'`?  If you're doing that in a separate python script, those changes will not persist into the selenium script.

Comment: It is in a separate python script. Where should it be then?

Comment: The typical place to set environment variables is in your shell startup file.  I don't know if mac has a GUI interface for setting them.

Comment: It seems that there isn't a clear way to set permanent environment variables on Mac. I actually looked at the link n1c9 sent and even after following it (the permanent section), the environment variables didn't show up within the program after calling them via os.getenv. I open the bash profile and they are there...I'm still not sure how to adjust.

Comment: Could I somehow how direct my program to the bash profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your environment variables in a .env file and use the pytest plugin pytest-dotenv.

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-dotenv/

As an aside, you can also install your browser drivers so they are on your local machine so that eliminates the need to define the path to the driver in your script. Example: `brew install --cask chromedriver`. If you are running these in a CI system there are other solutions.